# App Engine Maven Plugin

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

What is the difference between com.google.appengine and com.google.cloud.tools

eg.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.62</version>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
     <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.1</version>
     <configuration>
       <stage.enableJarSplitting>true</stage.enableJarSplitting>
       <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
       <cloudSdkPath>/usr/foo/path/to/cloudsdk</cloudSdkPath>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.google.appengine` -> Was designed specifically for the App Engine structure (Older version). This is based on the [App Engine SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven).

`com.google.cloud.tools` -> This is the new [Google Cloud SDK-based plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-maven). This allows to use libraries outside of the App Engine environment. The Cloud SDK is also a set of command line tools (gcloud, gsutil, and bq).

As long as your work would be contained in the App Engine environment you can pick either of them, as you prefer. You could check more on the differences in [Migrating to the Cloud SDK-based Maven plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-maven)